# Is there a way to assign a data type to a register in C?

Tags: c, types, type-conversion

In C we use `sfr()` to declare a symbol as a special register, usually as int, is there a way to assign a data type to such register?

for example:

```
typedef struct {
    int LByte:8;
    int HByte:8;
} str;

sfrw(REG, REG_ADDR); // 16bit sfr
```

I want: `REG.HByte = 0xff`

and

```
sfrd(REG, REG_ADDR); // 32bit sfr (if it should be sfrd)
```

I want: `REG = 1.234e5`

Comment: In *some extensions of C* we use `sfr`. Which toolchain are you working with?

Comment: I'm now using msp430-gcc, sfr(x,x) is equivalent to sfr x = x